# How to pass a firebase data into a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to pass string into function that is in my javascript file

The variable {{data.title}} is accessible elsewhere in my html file but it seems I am missing something because the function is not receiving the variable as ''

```
        <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="favorites('{{data.title}}')">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-star-outline"></i>
                <span>Add to favorites</span>
        </a>
```

JS File:

```
  $scope.favorites = function (x) {
    console.log(x);
    // retrieve it (Or create a blank array if there isn't any info saved yet),
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo')) || [];;
    // add to it,
   favorites.push({ name: x});
    // then put it back.
    localStorage.setItem('favoritesInfo', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('favoritesInfo'));
  }
```

Comment: Why would you wrap the parameter "data.title" (which is already a string) in single quotes? You cannot use interpolation inside expressions, only inside HTML templates. Try `favorites(data.title)`. Not sure if this solves your problem, but it's a note for good practice. If it helped, let me know and I will set this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-click` directive expects an expression. You passed in a string with what you believed to be an interpolation.

You can only use interpolation (`{{ the return value of an expression/variable }}`) in templates, not in expressions.

So the right thing to do is `ng-click="favorites(data.title)"`.

**Using expressions in HTML templates**

Generally, when doing expressions inside an HTML template in AngularJS, you can access your scope variables as you usually would, without the `$scope` prefix.

So if in your controller you have something like this:

`$scope.title = 'News From Today';`

You can bind to it (expressions, right?) like so:

`<h1 ng-bind="title"></h1>`

Or via interpolation like so:

`<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`

Comment: Thank you, I am chugging along trying to learn web development and I knew I was missing some concept but thank you for explaining the solution thoroughly :)

Comment: @Doopler Best of luck in your path as a web developer! :)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the `ngClick`:

```
ng-click="favorites('{{data.title}}')"
```

As it stands, you're encasing the interpolated expression (`{{<exp>}}`) in a string: `'{{data.title}}'`, but try just passing it like so since inteprolation is only needed when displaying the value directly to the view:

```
ng-click="favorites(data.title)"
```